# Null Check a column value that can be Null without two DLookups?

Tags: vba, null

How do I remove one DLookup from code similar to this example?

```
Dim sCustomerName as String

If IsNull(DLookup("sName", "tblCustomers", "iCustomerID=12345")) Then
   MsgBox "Customer name is null!"
Else
   sCustomerName = DLookup("sName", "tblCustomers", "iCustomerID=12345")
End If
```

In VBA, reading a column value that can be Null (or missing) into a variable, and *then* comparing it to Null gives an error. Is there a better way to do these checks?

Obviously, if there's no performance penalty, it's not bad code because of the performance hit. *Is there?*

Even if not, it has duplicated/copy-pasted code. How can it be rewritten to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried declaring `sCustomerName` as a `Variant`? Then you can do (I think) one `DLookup` like so: `sCustomerName = DLookup: if IsNull(sCustomerName) etc.`

Answer (score 1):

A Variant data type can store Null values. Try to get the value and check if Null.

```
Dim customerName As Variant
    customerName = DLookup("sName", "tblCustomers", "iCustomerID=12345")

If Not IsNull(customerName) Then
    'do stuff
End If
```

Another approach is the [Nz()](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) function:

> You can use the Nz function to return zero, a zero-length string (" "), or another specified value when a Variant is Null.

```
Dim customerName As String
    customerName = Nz(DLookup("sName", "tblCustomers", "iCustomerID=12345"), vbNullString)

If customerName <> vbNullString Then
    'do stuff
End If
```

Comment: Thx. Variant is good for preserving the data, Nz is good for replacing it with a default. It's best to always specify the valueifnull parameter, since the documentation doesn't detail in which contexts you get a 0 back instead of "".

Comment: Indeed, I always specify the `valueifnull` parameter. I fell I have more control over it. As for the variant, its only purpose in this case is to handle the dbNull which throws an error.